# Pass parameters from SSRS report to snowflake using snowflake as datasoruce

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to pass the ssrs parameters to snowflake through the query window, however the fields or columns in the table are not being displayed for selection within the report.
Any suggestions?

Have tried both single and double quotes

Option 1:

```
="select ""OrderID"" from ""Database.schema"".""Test""  WHERE ""OrderID"" IN ( '"+ Parameters!OrderID.Value +"');"
```

Option 2:

```
"select OrderID from Test  WHERE OrderID IN ( '"+ Parameters!OrderID.Value +" ');"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg5OQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a question mark.

```
select OrderID from Test  WHERE OrderID IN ( ? );
```